# Swift: Subclass NSFileManager

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I need to subclass NSFileManager to add some need functions to it.
I created a subclass, added the functions and private variables, now I want to access the functions from another class like this. `MyFileManager.defaultManager().awesomeFunction("Test")`

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class AwesomeFileManager: NSFileManager {

    private let awesomeLet = ["let1", "let2", "let3"]

    func awesomeFunction(parameter: String) -> Bool! {
        return true
    }

}
```

Somehow I can not access the function from another class. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Swift 2.0

Comment: Did you actually write the `defaultManager` method on your subclass?

Comment: I would not subclass NSFileManager since defaultManager will always return an NSFileManager instance and not your subclass. Create your own object class or use a category/extensions on NSFileManager.

Comment: Why don't you use extensions to add more feature to NSFileManager? (However it does not support add properties, but only functions)

Answer (score 0):

Override `defaultManager` and make sure it returns an instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the subclassing of methods you need to access the new method, that task is better handled with an extension:

```
extension NSFileManager {

    private struct AssociatedKey {
        static var awesomeLet: [String]?
    }

    var awesomeLet: [String]? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.awesomeLet) as? [String]
        }

        set {
            if let value = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.awesomeLet, value, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC)
            }
        }
    }

    func awesomeFunction(parameter: String) -> Bool! {
        return true
    }

}
```

Because you can't add variables to an extensions, I gave you the code to add a associated key to store/retrieve any objects you want to add the extension.